# The program leaves the loop before going through all the values

Tags: c++

i and j values of the array are incorrect

I have tried checking for any places where i and j may change but havent seen any.

```
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<M; j++) {
        cin >> grid[j, i];

    }
}
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<M; j++) {
        cout << grid[j, i];

    }
    cout << "\n"
}
```

i gave input in a tabular form with n rows and m columns

```
2 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
2 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1
-1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 -1
```

but the answer
comes out to be

```
-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
-12
```

Comment: `grid[j,i]` what do you think this does?

Comment: You have *four* loops, which one is "leaving"? And have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger?

Comment: And please try to create a [mcve] to show us. What is `grid` really? How is it initialized? Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please take care to properly format your code before posting it. White space might not matter for the compiler, but it does for the humans you are asking help from.

Comment: `grid[j, i];` C++ is not FORTRAN or other language that uses the `,` to separate dimensions in an array.

Comment: C++ doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays in the sense that e.g. Fortran have it (as mentioned). What C++ have as a way to emulate a "2d" array is an array *of arrays*. Like e.g. `int grid[M][N]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grid[j, i]` will just throw away the `j` - so you're doing `grid[i]`, addressing a 1D array using `i` only.

`grid[i][j]` is the usual way to address elements in 2D arrays, which would work if you had declared it as `int grid[N][M]`.

If you have a 1D array (`int grid[N*M]`) and are using it to store 2D data then

`grid[j*N + i]` or `grid[j + i*M]`

looks like what you need.

---

Example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

// simulated cin
std::istringstream cin(
    "2 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1\n"
    "2 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1\n"
    "-1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1\n"
    "-1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1\n"
    "-1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1\n"
    "-1 -1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1\n"
    "-1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 -1\n");

int main() {
    constexpr int N = 7;
    constexpr int M = 8;
    int grid[N * M];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            cin >> grid[j + i * M];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << grid[j + i * M];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 2 1 1 1-1-1-1-1
 2 1 1 1-1-1-1-1
-1 1 1 1-1-1-1-1
-1 1 1 1-1-1-1-1
-1 1 1 1 1-1-1-1
-1-1 1 1 1 1-1-1
-1-1 1 1 1 1 1-1
```

Comment: The problem is that the actual output shown in the question isn't pointers. So `grid` *isn't* a "2d" array. But then that might actually be cause of the problem the OP is having?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right. Added info.